# How to display images into another page using navigation query string in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, navigation

i'm not able to display the images to another page. The images are taken from json. So i'm trying to pass the image url of the selected item of a listbox into a navigagtion query string.The variable i'm trying to pass the data is showing as null.Plese provide me with solution. Thanks

Here the code of the first page:

```
 private void ImageList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var lbi = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem;


            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)

            {

                Uri targetPage = new Uri("/DisplayPhoto.xaml?selectedItem="+ lbi.ToString(),UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                NavigationService.Navigate(targetPage);

            }
            ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

Code of the second page:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedIndex = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out    selectedIndex))
            {

                Uri uri = new Uri(selectedIndex, UriKind.Absolute);
                var img = new Image();
                img.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                img.Height = 400;
                img.Width = 400;
                listBox1.Items.Add(img);
            }
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape your parameters with `Uri.EscapeUriString`

```
Uri targetPage = new Uri("/DisplayPhoto.xaml?selectedItem="+ Uri.EscapeUriString(lbi.ToString()),UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); 
NavigationService.Navigate(targetPage);
```

Comment: the code u provided is not giving error but it is not displaying the image

Comment: Can you pls debug and provide an example what is your navigation uri?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer sending data via some static property, preferably inside the `App` class. This way you can "send" complex objects from one page to another.